# Ubuntu 17.10 always booting grub

Tags: grub2, 17.10

This morning my Dell XPS 9560 got in an endless grub reload loop. So I reinstalled grub2 using boot-repair and now it's working again. But every time I reboot now, grub is shown. I'm fairly new to Ubuntu so this is all very new to me. How can this be fixed?

One detail, I've disabled `quiet splash` on `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Also not unimportant, if I reboot using the first option in the grub menu (Ubuntu), there is just a black screen. I need to go into the **Advanced options...** sub-menu and select the **Ubuntu, with Linux...** (not recovery) option.

Comment: How did you disable it?

Comment: Please set your `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` then `sudo update-grub` and `reboot`, still don't know what you meant by disabled!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to define the timeout that way. With **disabled** I meant `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` instead of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`.